# php new line ignored

Tags: php, html

below is the part of php script in which i try to write order details to a file. I want every order to start from the new line but somehow the '\n' in the $ciagwyjsciowy part is ignored and i end up with 10 orders in one line. I searched the forum and found that it can be done with doublequotes ( already there ) or break from html but none of this works.

```
@ $wp = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../zamowienia/zamowienie.txt", 'ab');
    flock($wp, LOCK_EX);

    if (!$wp) {
        echo "<p><strong> Zamowienie nie moze zostac w tej chwili przyjete.
        Prosze sprobowac pozniej.</strong></p></body></html>";
        exit;
    }
    $ciagwyjsciowy = $data."  ".$iloscrekawic."rekawic  ".$iloscochraniaczy."ochraniaczy  ".$iloscworkow."workow  ".$wartosc."PLN  ".$adres."\n";
fwrite($wp, $ciagwyjsciowy);
flock($wp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($wp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `\n`, use `PHP_EOL`. This returns the correct end of line constant for your platform. For *nix, this is `\n` whereas for Windows this is `\r\n`.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol

Comment: @Hybrydyzacja2422 No problem :) Please accept this answer once you are able if it's helped you.